# Custom access to an app

Tags: django

I've a little question about Django and authorisations.
I have an app which has to be accessible via user who is in a certain kind of organisation.
e.g: if user is in organisation type 1, he can, else, he cannot.

Should i work with permissions or with a custom middleware ?

Comment: you can use the `group` and `permissions` in `django.contrib.auth`

Comment: organisations are managed in an app, i don't want to use groups to do that

Answer (score 0):

Use `user_passes_test` decorator to do it.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required,user_passes_test
def is_auth(u):
    #u is the request.user
    if user_auth_for_page(u):
            return True
    return False

def user_auth_for_page(u):
    #your Authentication function here
    #if user is in org1 return true

@user_passes_test(lambda u: is_auth(u),login_url='/home/')
@login_required
def page(request):
    ...
```

Again, the best approach would be to use it in conjuction with the django groups.

```
def is_auth(u,g):
    l=u.groups.all()
    for i in l:
        if i.name==g:
            return True
    return False
@user_passes_test(lambda u: is_auth(u,'admin'),login_url='/home/')
```